# Having problems with Azure virtual machines and REST api

Tags: rest, azure, authentication, virtual-machine

Im trying to start Azure VM programmatically (using management certificate). Im getting this error when trying to process http request: error 401 Unauthorized. (thats not an error that appears when certificate is wrong). Tried other request to the same subscription(list hosted services) - went ok, seems like the problem appears only when im tryin to work with virtual machines. Have no idea what am i doing wrong. Here's the code:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Certificate = new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(base64Cer));

        string uriFormat = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{my_sub_id}/resourceGroups/{my_resourse_group}/providers/Microsoft.ClassicCompute/virtualMachines/{my_machine_name}/start?api-version={0}";

        Uri uri = new Uri(string.Format(uriFormat, Version));

        XDocument responseBody;
        HttpWebResponse response = InvokeRequest(uri, "POST", out responseBody);

        HttpStatusCode statusCode = statusCode = response.StatusCode;
        Console.WriteLine("The status of the operation: {0}\n\n", statusCode.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(responseBody.ToString(SaveOptions.OmitDuplicateNamespaces));


        Console.Write("Press any key to continue:");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static HttpWebResponse InvokeRequest( Uri uri, string method, out XDocument responseBody)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Method = method;
        request.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", Version);
        request.ClientCertificates.Add(Certificate);
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.ContentLength = 0;

        responseBody = null;
        HttpWebResponse response;
        try
        {
            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            response = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
        }
        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore;
        if (response.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(response.GetResponseStream(), settings))
            {
                try
                {
                    responseBody = XDocument.Load(reader);
                }
                catch
                {
                    responseBody = null;
                }
            }
        }
        response.Close();
        return response;
    }
```

Comment: Can you pls show the request? Using Fiddler or something like that. Looks like there is something missed.

Comment: @AlexBelotserkovskiy Is that what you've been asking for? 
http://puu.sh/pcLm4/aed3966230.png

Comment: It says i needed authorization header, but which one?

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're getting this error is because you're trying to authenticate/authorize an `Azure Resource Manager (ARM)` API request with an X509 Certificate. Authorization of ARM API requires `Azure AD based authorization token`. Please see this link for authenticating/authorizing an ARM API request: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790557.aspx.

X509 Certificate based authentication/authorization works only for Classic Service Management API requests.